# SQL Server : cursor Inserting a line if one doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, insert, cursor, exists, not-exists

I've got the following query - a cursor that cycles through a table `ltr_program` pulling a column (`id`) inserting that value into a newly created table. It also adds an id field to the newly created table.

I am having a hard time adding logic to say only add that id if it doesn't already exist in the target table (The job will run periodically and new id's will be added as time goes on). I want the code to  be more dynamic only adding newly created data.

```
DECLARE @next int, @program int

DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT id
    FROM ltr_program

OPEN insert_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor INTO @program   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN   
    SET @next = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM LTR_Budget) + 1                     

    INSERT INTO LTR_Budget (id, ProgramID) 
        SELECT @next, @program 

    FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor INTO @program   
END   

CLOSE insert_cursor
DEALLOCATE insert_cursor
```

Thank you,

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Can't be both I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server (that is what happens when you click add to fast)

Comment: Don't use a cursor for this. This should be a single insert statement. And of course you have potential issues with concurrency here when using a "roll your own" incrementing value instead of using an identity.

Comment: I updated my id field to be an identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
INSERT INTO LTR_Budget (id, ProgramID)
SELECT @next, @program
where @program NOT IN (select distinct ProgramID from LTR_Budget)

FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor INTO @program
```

However, you really should think about rewriting this without the cursor.
You could make id (in LTR_Budet) an IDENTITY column that automatically increments with each insert, and rewrite this as:

```
INSERT INTO LTR_Budget (id, ProgramID)
SELECT id as ProgramID 
FROM ltr_program where id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProgramID from LTR_Budget)
```

That would be much cleaner.

Comment: I updated the id field to be an identity. thank you this worked!

Comment: Definitely.  Didn't mention this in answer, but you'll probably want to throw an index on the identity column.  Lot's of times people put a PRIMARY KEY on there (since it's guaranteed to be unique and NOT NULL)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @next INT;
SET @next = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM LTR_Budget);

INSERT INTO LTR_Budget (id, ProgramID)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.id) + @next,
    p.id
FROM
    ltr_program p
LEFT JOIN
    LTR_Budget b
        ON p.id = b.id
WHERE
    b.id IS NULL;
```